# Playn - is it possible to deploy on Apache server?

Tags: java, gwt, playn

I understand that it's a GWT, but if it compiles to Javascript, can the generated html module compile to such a packaging that I can just deploy it on Apache, assuming I don't have any backend communications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This is basically what I was getting at with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10203455/1093087). For the HTML port, you are effectively building a GWT application, which is just an HTML page hosting a bunch of cleverly obfuscated Javascript.

You can find the relevant Google documentation here:

- [How do I change the location of my cache/nocache HTML files?](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/FAQ_DebuggingAndCompiling#How_do_I_change_the_location_of_my_cache/nocache_HTML_files?)